# Can asyncpg be used as database client for mysql?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, asyncpg

Currently my company uses Mysql as server database

and I want to develop api with (FastAPI + sqlalchemy with asyncpg) stack

because I read a blog says "if you want to maximize performance of FastAPI, you should consider combination of fastapi and asyncpg"

but I guess asyncpg is database client for PostgreSQL which is not currently used in company Im working now.

document told me to create async engine with

```
engine = create_async_engine('postgresql+asyncpg://user:pass@server_addr/database', pool_size=20 ,echo=True, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

but can I use this code for connection with Mysq? Would it work?

If it doesn't, what kind of client should I use for async sqlalchemy?
(like `engine = create_async_engine('mysql+aiomysql: ...')`)

Comment: Seems so per [reference manual](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.aiomysql). or [mysql_asyncmy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.asyncmy).

Comment: can I know the difference between aiomyql and asyncmy?
Also, would asyncpg do not support mysql which the blog called as best practice?

Comment: Just because a blog exists doesn't mean much. `asyncpg` won't mention mysql because the async implementation is dependent on database. Given these are all pretty interchangeable with minimal effort I recommend bench-marking them against your application.